# Is there a different way to count repetitions in a string except count?

Tags: python, cs50

I'm doing CS50 DNA problem, and the python count function keeps returning off values, and I'm not sure why. I tried using find, but my implementation was wrong

```
import csv, sys
#check if all arguments are provided
if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("Usage: python dna.py data.csv sequence.txt")
    exit()

#sets database to first argument
databaseFile = sys.argv[1]

#sequence is second file
sequenceFile = sys.argv[2]

#make list for data
data = []
database = []

#open csv file
with open(databaseFile, 'r') as csvfile:

    #make reader
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

    #read in the headers
    fields = next(csvreader)
    fields.remove("name")

    #read in the rows of data in database
    for row in csvreader:
        #add data, with names and database with just numbers
        data.append(row)
        database.append([int(i) for i in row[1:]])

#open sequence
sequence = open(sequenceFile, 'r').readline()

results = []
#for add repetitions to results
for field in fields:
    results.append(sequence.count(field))

print(results)
found = False
for i in database:
    if (results == i):
        print(data[i])
        found = True
if not found:
    print("No match")
```

Which other method can i use to count the repetitions of 'field' in sequence
for example when i load:

python dna.py databases/large.csv sequences/19.txt
I get results as:
`[47, 40, 34, 11, 24, 31, 60, 26]`
`No match`

instead of fred
which is: `[37, 40, 10, 6, 5, 10, 28, 8]`

problem can be found at: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/6/dna/

Comment: `and the python count function keeps returning off values, and I'm not sure why. ` Can you make an example?

Comment: i have made an edit

Comment: I think the counts should be for consecutive occurrences whereas your count is all of the STRs in the strand - am I getting this right? The count you are getting is not consecutive I think.

Comment: how do i get consecutive counts?

Comment: You could make this question much easier to test by posting a sample field and sequence that does not count the way you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a regular expression to find consecutive matches.

```
import re

s = 'AGTCAGTCAGTCTTTTAGCTAGTC'
STR = 'AGTC'

strands = re.findall(f'(?:{STR})+', s)
print(strands) # prints `['AGTCAGTCAGTC', 'AGTC']`

my_max = max(map(len, strands))//len(STR)
print(my_max)
```

Prints `3` which is correct as it appears 3 times consecutively (and once more at the end of the sequence).

I hope this snippet can help for this portion of your problems.

Comment: I tested this code and it works on the OP's data. You just need to wrap it in a function: `def longest_rep(s, tgt): return max(len(m) for m in re.findall(f'(?:{tgt})+', s)) // int(len(tgt))`

Comment: Additionally, after that fix, the loop starting after `print(results)` is failing. The reason is unclear, and the spec is not clear on what exactly should be the output. The loop does identify *Fred*, though.

Comment: i made a modification based on this. Thank you so much ````for field in fields:
    strands = re.findall(f'(?:{field})+', sequence)
    results.append(max(map(len, strands))//int(len(field)))````